# How to arrange, group and concentrate string values of repeated keys in different column using R

Tags: r, dictionary, dplyr, key, tidyr

I have an HMMSCAN result file of protein domains with 10 columns. please see the link for the CSV file.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10d_YQwD41uj0q5pKinIo7wElhDj3BqilwWxThfIg75s/edit?usp=sharing

But I want it to look like this:-

```
1BVN:P|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE      Alpha-amylase      Alpha-amylase_C    A_amylase_inhib
3EF3:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE      Cutinase           
3IP8:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE      Amdase
4Q1U:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE      Arylesterase
4ROT:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE      Esterase           
5XJH:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE      DLH
6QG9:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE      Tannase
```

The repeated entries of column 3 should get grouped and its corresponding values of column 1, which are in different rows, should be arranged in separate columns.

This is what i wrote till now:

```
df <- read.csv ("hydrolase_sorted.txt" , header = FALSE, sep ="\t")
new <- df %>% select (V1,V3) %>% group_by(V3) %>% spread(V1, V3)
```

I hope I am clear with the problem statement. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. If you could show us what you have tried that will be a good place to start. Also please post a REPRoducible EXample (reprex) so that people could be encouraged to assist you. If your data is in a form that forces others to manually construct then you may not get many pointers.

Comment: I have tried dplyr and tidyr packages till now. this is what I wrote:    `````df <- read.csv("hydrolase_sorted.txt", header=false, sep ="\t")         \n                                            new <- df %>% select (V1,V3) %>% group_by(V3) %>% spread (V1, V3)

Comment: The format of your data is not clear, can you post data using `dput(df)` ? Read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: please see this link for the raw data:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10d_YQwD41uj0q5pKinIo7wElhDj3BqilwWxThfIg75s/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input data set has two unregular rows. However, the approach in your solution is right but one more step is required:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(V3,V1) %>% group_by(V3) %>% mutate(x = paste(V1,collapse=" ")) %>% select(V3,x)
```

What we did here is simply concentrating strings by `V3`. Before running the abovementioned code in this solution you should preprocess and fix some improper rows manually. The rows (TIM, Dannase, and DLH). To do that you can use the *Convert texts into column* function of in Excel.

Required steps defined are below. Problematic columns highlighted yellow:

[image: First Step]
[image: Second Step]
[image: Third steps]

Sorry for the non-English interface of my Excel but the way is self-explanatory.

Comment: please see the edits I have made in the problem statement. thanks for the help. really appreciate it11

Comment: I edited my answer. There was a small case 'v'. It should work now. Here the screenshot: https://ibb.co/vPHrbQv

Comment: Thanku so much for the help. it is sorted.

Comment: what if i want to add place each element in a different column? i.e, the collapsed values should be separated by tab